# SSAS How to Multiply two calculated measures without multiply the grand total (Excel)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have two measures, "Budget Qty" and its aggregation is SUM, and "_NSPPrice" and it is a calculated measure (Multiply another 3 measures). and I have created a new calculated meausre "Budget Amount (USD)" by multiply "Budget Qty" and "_NSPPrice" and the result is correct except the grand total, it multiplies the total of "Budget Qty" and total of "_NSPPrice" but I want the total to be the sum of "Budget Amount(USD)".

[image]

Comment: can you show the calculate measure mdx code ?

Comment: if you mean Budget Amount(USD) it is as following 
 Budget Qty * _NSPPrice

Answer (score 0):

For this, you could use the scope function to change the sum function of the measure.
Try something like

```
SCOPE([Product].[Product].[All],[Measures].[Budget Amount(USD)]);
    THIS = SUM([Product].[Product].[Product],[Measures].[Budget Amount(USD)]);
End SCOPE;
```

See Scope reference: [Scope function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/mdx-scripting-scope?view=sql-server-ver15)